# Windows 8.1 Home goes to the lock screen after 1 minute

Tags: windows, lock

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1 Home version and when I'm logged in as the main administrator account, if it is idle for 1 minute, the screen goes black and then goes to the lock screen when I move the mouse.

I've tried to change the power settings and disabled screensaver and such, but it is still persisting.

Comment: The lock screen is enabled/disabled through Right Click Desktop - Personalize - Screen Saver.

Comment: You may want to check in Task Manager whether there are a lot of startup programs. You can disable ALL except the AV program.